# Email Migration API v2: Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-email-migration

I am trying to write a `GAS` to migrate some emails which are stored in `Google Drive` but I am really struggling to get the POST correct to do this and was hoping someone could help me out and steer me in the right direction.

What I have so far is ..

```
  var id = "12345678abcdefgh";
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  var emlData = doc.getText();
  var api_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/email.migration';
  var app_name = "migration";
  var userKey = "someone@mygappsdomain.com";
  var method = "POST";

  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/email/v2/users/"+userKey+"/mail?uploadType=multipart";


  var fields =  {"MailItem" : 
                  {"properties":
                   {'isInbox': 'true','isUnread': 'true'},
                   'labels': ['MigrateMe']}};

  var options = {payload: {data: JSON.stringify(emlData), fields: fields, contentType: 'multipart/related', boundary : 'part_boundary'}};
  var fetchArgs = googleOauth_(app_name,api_scope,method,options);
  try
  {
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getResponseCode();
    Logger.log("done");
  }
  catch (ee) 
  {
    Logger.log(ee);
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work and I get a 400 error code. Do you know what could be wrong ?

Comment: did you tried to make it work in the api playground? https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ Also I saw you where using somewhere in your code multipart (for what I know it's really sensitive to carrier return --> got stuck hours because I forgotten one)

Comment: Thanks Harold, I'll have a play in the playground and see if I can get it to work there.

Comment: I can't even to get it to work in the playground. I think I may have to give up on this one, it is frustratingly just out of reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As spoken in comment here an exemple to do it with the playground api:

**step 1:**
Authorise: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/email.migration

**step 2:**
Authorize blbablablabla (you know what to do here)

**step 3:**
You need to do a POST to hte URL:
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/email/v2/users/**EMAILADRESS@DOMAIN.EXT**/mail

The Content-type need to be set on: custom...
and the arguments are:

```
uploadType:media
Content-Type:message/rfc822
```

the request body must look at something like this:

```
Date: Wed, 03 Jan 2013 02:56:03 -0800
From: admin@example.org
To: liz@example.com
Subject: Hello World!
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252
Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit

And I think to myself... What a wonderful world!
```

(you can take exactly this one to do some test and then in your mailbox search for "liz")

If everything worked you should have something like this:
[image]

To do this I used the documentation found here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-migration/v2/guides/upload
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-migration/v2/reference/mail/insert

This is not the solution to your post, but I Hope it will help you to get it! (and by the way if you get to have a nice working code please give the real answer to your question - I'm also interested)

Comment: Thankyou, That works great in the playground. I will convert this into a script now and let you know the final code. Thanks so much for the pointer.

Comment: Thankyou Harold, I now have a basic working script :) 

If you can advise how to do a multipart from this so I can send metaData (labels isInbox etc) then I would have a final script.

https://script.google.com/d/1C8X-22do-U3BG6mK37X1O1AeHDlsUGwRaf4KOOsQxUV-7ehHMjWUULzj/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**Script**

I took the liberty to rebuild here the differents parts of your comment:

```js
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("MailTemplate");
template.sentDate = "Wed, 04 Mar 2014 02:56:03 -0800";
template.from = "sender.address@blahblah.com";
template.to = "recipient.address@blahblah.com";
template.subject = "second test";
template.body = "I was migrated via script !!!!";
template.sentDate = eml_sentDate;
template.from = eml_from;
template.to = eml_to;
template.subject = eml_subject;
template.body = eml_body;
var emlData = template.evaluate().getContent();
var api_scope = 'googleapis.com/auth/email.migration';;
var app_name = "migration";
var userKey = "recipient.address@blahblah.com";
var method = "POST";

var url = "googleapis.com/upload/email/v2/users/" + userKey + "/…"; 
var options = { method : 'POST', contentType: 'message/rfc822', uploadType: 'media', payload: emlData };


var fetchArgs = googleOauth_(app_name, api_scope, method);
fetchArgs.payload = emlData;
fetchArgs.contentType = 'message/rfc822';
fetchArgs.uploadType = 'media';
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getResponseCode();
```

**Multipart**

What I can give you to du multipart: it's a part of a script that is dedicated to do batch request to google api (it was designed to add users to a google group). The batch is done through a multipart file so I suppose it's quite the same thing than for your mail:

```js
function batchRequest(userArray,grpEmail){
  var grpEmail = grpEmail || "testgroup@domain.ext";
  //var postUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/"+grpEmail+"/members";
  var postUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch';
  var accessToken = refreshAccessToken();
  var userEmail = ""
  var boundary = 'batch_foobarbaz';
  var  payload = "";

  for(var i in userArray){
  payload+= '--'+boundary+'\nContent-Type: application/http\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n';
  payload+='POST /admin/directory/v1/groups/'+grpEmail+'/members HTTP/1.1\n';
  payload+= 'Content-type: application/json\n\n';
  payload+='{"email": "'+userArray[i]+'", "role": "MEMBER"}\n';
  }
  payload+='--'+boundary+'--';

   var params={
     method:'POST',
    contentType:'multipart/mixed; boundary="'+boundary+'"',
     headers:{
       Authorization:" OAuth "+accessToken  
     },
      payload:payload,
     muteHttpExceptions:true
   }
  var requestResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(postUrl, params);
  var result = requestResponse.getContentText();
  Logger.log(requestResponse.getResponseCode()+" - "+result);
  return(requestResponse.getResponseCode());

}
```