# is there is possible to migrate email to the gmail account

Tags: google-api, office-2013, outlook-2013, google-email-migration, office-app

i want to develop office app and i want to sync email from outlook to Google account.
then,

which scope i use?

how to pass email data to URL and on which URL?

if possible to give me example

i use this two scope for authentication or to get user info.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

i refer this stack overflow link :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013904/email-migration-api-v2-google-apps-script)

another question is i can migrate email to **example@gmail.com(gmail account)**?
i use a **Google playground** to check email migrate scope then it give error to invalid access of API and it proper work if i use **example@domain.com** to migrate email.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to migrate emails from outlook to GApps, you should use the email migration API scope:
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/migration/

Google also has an official tool that you can use to sync Outlook to GApps.  https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync <- check it out.

Comment: thnks..i use this scope for migrate ..`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/email.migration` but how to pass a email body on api scope url??

Comment: an another question is i can migrate email to example@gmail.com (gmail account)??

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but might be useful for someone else..

to @gmail accounts - **Mail Fetcher**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gphzjf6sLRc

However this does not preserve folder structure.

Options like **GAMMO** (https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration) and **GAMME**(https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration) work only for migrations TO a business Google For Work account, not to personal gmail. GAMME also migrates between IMAP servers.

Another option is to export your PST file, put it in Outlook, sync your @gmail.com and drag/drop emails to your gmail PST which will sync up to the server. **There is a chance of losing data though!**